# How to write jQuery-AJAX function to append the list items received from PHP and show the "Loading..." message until he response is recieved?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, response

I'm having one select control on a form. I want to populate the select control with list values that comes from PHP file in the form of AJAX response. How should I do this and how should I show the 'Loading...' message until the response is received from PHP file?

```
<label class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 control-label">Select Store<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span> :</label>

<input type="hidden" name="module_url" id="module_url" value="http://localhost/modules/stores/stores.php">
```

The necessary PHP code snippet is as follows :

```
switch( $op ) { 
case "get_all_stores":

      // to get all the available stores.
      $ret_store = $objStore->GetAllStoreByPage(''); 

      if(!$ret) { 
        $error_msg = $objStore->GetAllErrors();
        $data = array();
        $data['error_message'] = $error_msg;
        $data = json_encode($data);
        echo $data;
        die;
      } else {
        $data = array();
        $data = $objStore->GetResponse();
        echo json_encode($data);
        die;
      }    
          break;
}
```

The jQuery-AJAX code that I tried is as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var module_url = $('#module_url').val(); 
$.ajax({
        url : module_url,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        data: {
          'request_type':'ajax', 
          'op':'get_all_stores'
        },
        success: function(result, success) {
           //What to write here in order to append the data items to the select control and show the 'Loading...' message until response is received

        } else {
            //What to write to put error messages
          } 
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: Before the ajax call add a text `loading...` to the container where you want to display the text and in success remove the text. For appending the items, try to print the `result` in console and then accordingly access the values. Eg. result.id, result.name etc

Comment: I don't see why you're using ajax at all here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like best way would be like this:

1. disable sync ajax (it will block UI until response ends and we don't need that to achieve loading indication),
2. begin with showing loading (in modal window or some div with highest z-index (modal if you would like to force user waiting),
3. on ajax complete event hide loading
4. on ajax success (and maybe failure) act as needed

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your PHP code prepares the population of the `Select` control, let's assume that your PHP code returns something like

```
<OPTION value="1">One</OPTION>
<OPTION value="2">Two</OPTION>
<OPTION value="3">Three</OPTION>
```

Then, all you need is a place holder for your `Loading...` message.. Let's say:

```
<div id='myWaitLabel'></div>
```

and your javascript should be modifed (use `error` instead of `else` to indicate what function to execute when there is an error)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var module_url = $('#module_url').val(); 
$('#myWaitLabel').html('Loading... Please wait');
$.ajax({
        url : module_url,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        data: {
          'request_type':'ajax', 
          'op':'get_all_stores'
        },
        success: function(result, success) {
           $('#myWaitLabel').html('');
           $('#mySelectID').html(result);

        },
        error: function() {
            $('#myWaitLabel').html('Sorry, an error occured');
          } 
        }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript as:-

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var module_url = $('#module_url').val(); 
        $.ajax({
                url : module_url,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                data: {
                  'request_type':'ajax', 
                  'op':'get_all_stores'
                },
                success: function(result, success) {
                //append your response here as
                $('#element').after(result);
               //or use
                $('#element').append(result);
                 },
            error: function(a,b,c)
            {
                //fbalert('Error', 'Error occured. Please try again.');
            },
        beforeSend: function(){

                     // Handle the beforeSend event          
                    $("#loading_msg").removeClass("visibility_hidden").addClass("visibility_visible");
            },
            complete: function(){
                        // Handle the complete event
                $("#loading_msg").removeClass("visibility_visible").addClass("visibility_hidden");
                    }


          });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For loading message

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var module_url = $('#module_url').val(); 
$('#loading').html('<p> loading...</p>'); // #loading is a id to a div element
$.ajax({
        url : module_url,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        data: {
          'request_type':'ajax', 
          'op':'get_all_stores'
        },
        success: function(result, success) {
            $('#loading').html(''); // when success remove message

        } else {
             $('#loading').html('Error Occurred Please try again '); // when error 
          } 
        }
      });
});
```